# Is there a way to manipulate included JS without eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

I know lots of people think "eval is evil," but I have to accomplish something and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it without eval().

The situation is this: an external file (I have no control over it--EDIT: but it's not user-generated. It's from a trusted source! I imagine this is important) is spitting out JavaScript for me to use. This JavaScript contains some nice JSON data (which is what I need to get), but it's flanked by ordinary JavaScript statements declaring variables and calling functions and such. It looks kinda like this:

```
var foo = new Object();
foo['KEY'] = {Field1: 'Value1', Field2: 'Value2'};
eval('fooFunction(foo)');
```

If I eval() this, I can just parse foo['KEY'] and be done with it. The only way I can think to do this without eval() is with a bunch of annoying replace()ments, which hardly seems better. Am I missing some obvious way to do this? Most of the "you don't have to use eval()" alternatives I usually see assume I have complete control over everything, but in this case I have to work around this existing code.

EDIT: I should add that this code is being obtained via an AJAX call from a proxy script (cross-domain stuff), so none of the variables are accessible. If they were, I'd obviously just be able to parse foo['KEY'] and be on my merry.

SECOND EDIT: nothing conclusive yet! I'm getting dangerously close to concluding that eval() is the way to go. Can you stomach this outcome? I'm about to give in to evil(). Somebody stop me, because it's looking like the only way.

Comment: `If I eval() this` - are you trying to eval something that's already evaling something else? O.o Also "replacements" are definitely more secure (and thus: better), especially when you have no control over the script.

Comment: I know it seems silly, but hey, that's why I'm here.

Re: replacements. That would involve something like five or six replacements, most likely, including having to replace \r and \n and other things like that. Beyond clunky. Gotta think there's a better way.

Comment: Why not just look for anything between `{` and `}` and try parse as JSON? Should be simple enough with regex, no replace is required. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little worried that this will mean rewriting it fairly often (for a few reasons), but that might be my best option. I'm pretty lousy at RegExp though, but I guess that might be the way to go. If you post it as an answer and all that I can probably mark it accepted. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Actually it's going to be problematic with nested `{}`. But I'm sure there's a workaround.

Comment: I'm sure RegExp is not the tool for this task.

Comment: Why's that? And if it isn't...does that mean eval() is? Have I discovered the lone scenario under which it's necessary? ;)

Comment: @ChrisBowyer done. When replying to comments please ping the user with `@` like I did now otherwise good chance the one you reply to won't see you replied.

Comment: @freakish true, I ditched regex and came up with raw string manipulation, from some experiments it appears to work fine with nested blocks. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the tip, will do from now on. I think I subconsciously assumed that didn't work based on the fact that they didn't look like links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external code better send back valid JSON. The value in your example is not valid JSON, as the keys must be wrapped with double quote.

I came up with small pure JavaScript parser, that can handle simple invalid JSON by adding double quotes by itself. It currently won't support non string values.

```
function ParseRawJSON(rawCode) {
    var arrCandidates = [];
    var lastOpenBracketIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < rawCode.length; i++) {
        var curChar = rawCode.charAt(i);
        if (curChar === "}") {
            if (lastOpenBracketIndex >= 0) {
                arrCandidates.push(rawCode.substr(lastOpenBracketIndex, i - lastOpenBracketIndex + 1));
                lastOpenBracketIndex = -1;
            }
        } else if (curChar === "{") {
            lastOpenBracketIndex = i;
        }
    }

    var arrJsonObjects = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrCandidates.length; i++) {
        var currentJSON = null;
        try {
            currentJSON = JSON.parse(arrCandidates[i]);
        } catch (e) {
            //try fixing
            var fixedCandidate = TryFixJSON(arrCandidates[i]);
            if (fixedCandidate) {
                try {
                    currentJSON = JSON.parse(fixedCandidate);
                } catch (e) {
                    currentJSON = null;
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentJSON != null) {
            var keys = [];
            for (var key in currentJSON)
                keys.push(key);
            if (keys.length > 0)
                arrJsonObjects.push(currentJSON);
        }
    }
    return arrJsonObjects;

    function Trim(s, c) {
        if (c instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
                s = Trim(s, c[i]);
            return s;
        }
        if (typeof c === "undefined")
            c = " ";
        while (s.length > 0 && s.charAt(0) === c)
            s = s.substr(1, s.length - 1);
        while (s.length > 0 && s.charAt(s.length - 1) === c)
            s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1);
        return s;
    }

    function TryFixJSON(strBlock) {
        if (strBlock.indexOf(":") <= 0)
            return false;
        strBlock = strBlock.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
        var mainParts = strBlock.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < mainParts.length; i++) {
            var currentPart = Trim(mainParts[i]);
            if (currentPart.indexOf(":") <= 0)
                return false;
            var subParts = currentPart.split(":");
            if (subParts.length !== 2)
                return false;
            var currentKey = Trim(subParts[0], [" ", "'", "\""]);
            var currentValue = Trim(subParts[1], [" ", "'", "\""]);
            if (currentKey.length === 0)
                return false;
            subParts[0] = "\"" + currentKey + "\"";
            subParts[1] = "\"" + currentValue + "\"";
            mainParts[i] = subParts.join(":");
        }
        return "{" + mainParts.join(", ") + "}";
    }
}
```

This will just look for anything between `{` and `}` and try to parse as JSON. No eval, in case of failure it'll just ignore the invalid block. Success? Great, it will return plain array of the valid JSON's it found.

Usage example:

```
var rawCode = "var foo = new Object(); { dummy here }}} function boo() {}" + 
"foo['KEY'] = { \"Field1\": \"Value1\", \"Field2\": \"Value2\"}; hello {\"foo\": \"bar\"} and it's over ";
var jsonObjects = ParseRawJSON(rawCode);
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
    for (var key in jsonObjects[i]) {
        var value = jsonObjects[i][key];
        //got key and value...
    }
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/HpqUC/6/), using fixed version of your sample code.

Comment: First: thank you for this incredible amount of work. Second, that's the format I get it in, so I don't know if the parser will work with it, which makes me feel bad because you've been so generous with your time. I should note that, if I use eval(), I can just loop through the data with each() even though it's not valid JSON, which is just as good on my end. Any array/JSON/whatever I can manipulate into whatever format I need. But assuming it did work, this does seem to look like a situation where eval() makes a lot of sense, no? If the alternative is this intricate custom parser, I mean.

Comment: @Chris not all is lost, will try to improve the parser to support values like in your example.

Comment: Many thanks either way. But I would definitely be interested to hear your thoughts on the more philosophical question involved. If ever eval() were justified, wouldn't it be a situation in which it was the difference between one line of code and 30?

Comment: Addendum: is it significant that I "trust" the source of this code and it isn't generated by users or through form input? All the security risks associated with eval() seem to fall by the wayside given those things.

Comment: @Chris first of all, I want to address your first comment. Don't feel bad; Stack Overflow is meant for all programmers, so having something useful for others is more than enough. As for your "philosophical question" regarding `eval` the plain answer is "no, it's always bad". In your specific case if you really 100% trust the source that it won't send you malicious code then go ahead, but by posting here in the first place I think you know deep down that it's not 100% but only 99% and there's always 1% chance malicious code will find its way to the user.

Comment: Well, the other reason to post this--which happens to be the one that describes me--is that it's a simple expression of doubt about my own level of expertise. I'm not a security expert, but I've heard more learned programmers say it's bad, even though I can't imagine why in this context given that the source of the code is trustworthy. I'm mainly posting it for all the possible reasons I don't know and can't think of. I'm asking about it more because, as I hear those reasons, I'm wondering if they apply in this circumstance. They seem to apply mostly to user input.

Comment: @ChrisBowyer take a look now. :)

Comment: Works. :) I think in this case eval() probably makes sense given the trustworthiness of the source, but this does, indeed, seem to provide a non-eval solution and I'll definitely hang onto it. Thank you! Always interested in any further opinions you have about eval() in general, too, and if this represents a rare example of it being reasonable to use.

Comment: @ChrisBowyer cheers, I  was never fan of `eval` to begin with, always looked like a hack to me and put in place without enough planning and considering the risks.

Answer (score 2):

A generally safer alternative to using `eval` is creating a [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and passing it the string function body. That way (unless something is explicitly acessing the `window` object) you won't have access to the global scope and can keep it encapsulated in the function scope.

Let's say the first two lines of your example code are the JavaScript that you'd like to evaluate, if you know the name of the variable you want to retrieve as a JSON object you can just return it at the end of the created function and then call it:

```
var js = "var foo = {}; foo['KEY'] = {Field1: 'Value1', Field2: 'Value2'};";
var fn = new Function(js + ';return foo;');
var result = fn();

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

This is also what MDN suggests doing in the [documentation for eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.

Comment: How is that safer then eval? Evil hackers will definitely write code using `window`.

Comment: Yes but you have more control over the scope and it is easier to override things you want to prevent from being used (like `alert` etc.) locally.

Comment: @freakish you can't protect the global scope this way, but you will protect your own lexical scope

Comment: @freakish It's just inside a closure, but it's not safe in this case at least eval is semantic, you just sweeping it under the carpet.

Comment: There's no functional difference between this and calling `eval` in a separate scope. And both are insecure.

Comment: This is also mentioned in the MDN documentation for `eval`. I added the according quote to my answer. That being said, evaluating potentially insecure third party code is generally not a good idea and there usually are more secure alternatives.

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Use_functions_instead_of_evaluating_snippets_of_code link talks about using functions object rather than raw js code where function is expected. It doenst talk about anything for this case.

Comment: It also seems to force me to create some dummy version of the fooFunction() function inside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON contains just data and not functions you can use `JSON.parse()`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse for more detailed info.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it doesn't contain just data. It's in the middle of other JavaScript code that I have no way of removing. I'm trying to get it to the point where I can use JSON.parse(). Doing it with the extra code obviously throws an error, because it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As the method has been placed in to the global, then you can do

```
window["fooFunction"](foo)
```

Comment: It's not actually in the global. It's being included from a proxy file for cross-domain purposes. I'm using an AJAX request to get it.